# Maxwell equations in vacuum gone wrong

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I am using the following set of equations for describing the electric  $(\mathbf{E})$ and the magnetic field ($\mathbf{B}$) in vacuum:

\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} & = 0 \\
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} & = 0 \\
\nabla \times \mathbf{E} & =  - \partial_t \mathbf{B} \\
\nabla \times \mathbf{B} & =  \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \partial_t \mathbf{E}
\end{align}

The following ansatz functions are used:

\begin{align}
& B_x = B_z = 0 \\
& B_y = B_0 \cos \omega t \cos \xi x \\
& E_x = E_y = 0 \\
& E_z = E_0 \sin \omega t \sin \xi x \\
\end{align}

For these ansatz functions, the first two divergence properties hold.

For the third equation, we have

$$
\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
-E_0 \xi \sin \omega t \cos \xi x \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and

$$
-\partial_t \mathbf{B} =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
B_0 \omega \sin \omega t \cos \xi x \\
0
\end{array}
\right),
$$

which requires that $-E_0 \xi = B_0 \omega$.

Accordingly, for the last equation we have that $\mu_0 \epsilon_0 \omega E_0 = -B_0 \xi$.

From my understanding, the equations are satisfied if $E_0/B_0 = -\omega/\xi$ and $(\mu_0 \epsilon_0)^{-1} = \omega^2/\xi^2$ hold.

But I do know they are wrong, since the electric and the magnetic fields should be in phase. Plus, my solution is a standing wave, and does not traverse in $x$-direction, as it should. What went wrong?

---

Yet another standing electromagnetic wave visualization:

[image]

Comment: You trial standing wave solutions, Why do you think they should be in phase? If this were the case there would be a violation of conservation of energy. Travelling waves are not the only solutions to the homogenous wave equation

Comment: It is stated here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_equations#Vacuum_equations,_electromagnetic_waves_and_speed_of_light

Comment: The Wikipedia article is referring to the aforementioned travelling wave solutions to the homogenous wave equation

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! So the standing wave solution is, in fact, yet another solution to the problem.

Comment: The question is about difficulties with elementary math. There's no shame un having such difficulties, especially if you have never taken a calculus course, but it is still a *homework question* and therefore off-topic.